# Why does Scala use the '_' operator for package import instead of '*' as in Java?

Tags: java, scala

In my opinion, one of the greatest things about Scala is its interoperability with Java and its similar syntax. One thing that I found strange is the use of the `_` operator for package wilcard imports instead of the `*` operator that is used in Java.

Is there a technical reason for using `_` instead of `*`? If not, then why was this change done?

Comment: This might just be a functional thing. I know Haskell uses _ in a few places to act as a wildcard/not-specified value.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Scala, the `*` is a valid identifier. One could write:

```
val * = "trollin'"
println(*)
```

With the result being:

```
trollin'
```

One could write a class named `*` as such:

```
class * {
  def test():String = {
    "trollin'"
  }
}
```

So with that being the case, when I have a class `*` in the package `us.hexcoder` and I write:

```
import us.hexcoder.*
```

You would be saying that you wish to import a class with the name `*`. Because of this, Scala needed to use another symbol to indicate a wildcard import. For whatever reason, they decided to use `_` as the wildcard symbol.

Comment: The question becomes then, why was * chosen as a valid identifier and _ as wildcard?

Comment: Even though I have more upvotes, this is the more correct answer. Never heard of * as an identifier before.

Comment: @MikeBrown It's also valid in Lisp. Here is an example in [Scheme](http://repl.it/I7u)

Comment: @MikePatridge Almost definitely because Scala defines all of its operators as functions, and allows the developer to define their own operators as such. It doesn't do special-case syntax for operators, and `*` needed to be included for multiplication. So another less common character needed to be chosen as a reserved character.

Comment: The _ character resembles a blank (as in "fill in the blank"), so whether Scala borrowed it from somewhere else or came up with it themselves, it makes sense to use it as a wildcard.

Answer (score 13):

In functional languages, the _ character is commonly used to say, "I don't care about this parameter" or "anything can go here". Extending that value to namespace imports only makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Glenn's answer, `import` is a valid statement anywhere in Scala and you can `import` an object or an instance members into scope. As `*` is obviously a member of many classes, it can not be used as a wildcard for the `import` statement. So you end up with a string which must not be a valid identifier.

`_` comes to mind. The fact that it is used in other places for a different meaning (existential type, function as an instance) is also due to the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala there are [dozens of places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala) where the underscore is used. Using it for wildcard imports is just a logical consequence.